# Unable to parse one of the two json strings which look identical

Tags: php, json

I used JSON.stringify to convert a JSON object to string, stored it in a database and retrieved it. When I am trying to decode it into json using json_decode(), it is returning NULL(I used var_dump() to verify it).

```
{"profilediv":" klsadnlksa ","profilediv2":" sankldnlkas ","profilediv3":" nsjakdnsjka "}

{"profilediv":"nsjakdnsjka","profilediv2":"sankldnlkas","profilediv3":"klsadnlksa"}
```

I am able to parse the second string, but not the first one. Here the entire code.

```
  <?php
$x = '{"profilediv":"

klsadnlksa

","profilediv2":"

sankldnlkas

","profilediv3":"

nsjakdnsjka

"}';
$x = trim($x);
$y = json_decode($x,true);
var_dump($y);
$json = '{"profilediv":"nsjakdnsjka","profilediv2":"sankldnlkas","profilediv3":"klsadnlksa"}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

And here is the output

```
NULL object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["profilediv"]=> string(11) "nsjakdnsjka" ["profilediv2"]=> string(11) "sankldnlkas" ["profilediv3"]=> string(10) "klsadnlksa" }
```

I am able to parse $json but not $x. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the linebreaks, they make the JSON invalid.

Comment: I have used trim for that purpose.Check the first code block in the question, both the strings look almost alike.

Comment: `trim()` doesn't trim anything from that string.  Only the start and end.

Comment: `trim` removes whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the string. Everything in between will persist.

Comment: How are you generating and retrieving this JSON? If it has random newlines, you should try fixing how you are saving the json instead of replacing or otherwise fixing the data afterwards.

Comment: okay, thanks will try it. Also I tried to use $x = str_replace("\n",'',$x); just like suggested in the comments. It is also of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to remove new-lines

```
$x = str_replace("\n",'',$x);
$y = json_decode($x,true);
```

Will be `var_dump`ed as:

```
Array
(
    [profilediv] => klsadnlksa
    [profilediv2] => sankldnlkas
    [profilediv3] => nsjakdnsjka
)
```

> **trim** — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the **beginning and end** of a string

Comment: I have used trim for that purpose.Check the first code block in the question, both the strings look almost alike.

Comment: yet it doesn't seem to do the job. Try this and let me know. I've tried it and it works.

Comment: do a `$x = trim($x);print_r($x);` and you'll see it doesn't work that way. trim only removes characters from the beginning and the end. Not in between

Answer (score 0):

```
function json_decode_with_new_lines($json, $assoc = TRUE){
   $json = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $json);
   $json = str_replace("\r", "", $json);
   return json_decode($json, $assoc);
}
```

Will give output:

```
Array
(
    [profilediv] => 

klsadnlksa


    [profilediv2] => 

sankldnlkas


    [profilediv3] => 

nsjakdnsjka


)
```